# what is the data type of "value" acsessed from properties file

Tags: java, properties

I am accessing value in my java file like mentioned bellow.So what is the data type of "value" acsessed from properties file. Iwanted to know which class needs to imported to use properties ?

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("path/filename"));
```

Comment: search the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 2):

Your values will be of String type, you can parse them into int / double / whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

```
 String     getProperty(String key) 
 Object     setProperty(String key, String value)
```

So you're storing and retrieving string values for each property key and each property value.